# Change length of right line

Tags: css, html

Please see  my [css](http://pastebin.com/8LGaXEmu) and [html5](http://pastebin.com/re6c4HQD)

How do I change the length of the right line and define its starting point? I don't know what to call it, but under the css-file, you can define its width under:

```
.border {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO. It'd help if you include a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) in the question itself, so that it's independent of any linked sites like pastebin.

Comment: A fiddle will be much more helpful

Comment: little advice - use http://jsfiddle.net/ for bigger examples :) It's much easier to debug such code for us

Comment: What do you mean by the "right" line?

Comment: A couple tips. 1: You'd better put all Your code in a jsfiddle or jsbin, so we van directly see the output of your code. 2: your html code also contains PHP. Although it is not much, it is preferred here to only add the code where the question is about. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Are you referring to `<div class="border-radius"><p id="border-radius-text"><a href="link" target="_blank">Some text here</a></p>`?

Comment: A CodePen with the relevant HTML/CSS: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/vGxpH

Comment: border-right on a block level element like `<article>` will always be the entire height of the block. You could set the height of your `<article>` explicitly or add padding to it to control the length of that border. What effect were you trying to achieve?

Comment: @httpgio well that's not very helpful, true as it may be :)

Comment: I added the code to fiddle (thanks for the suggestion). Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/WizzBane/3gJ2q/ It's the red line to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do a little research on CSS.

You can't exactly set the start and end point in the traditional sense, but you can do something like this...

`myitem { border-right:1px solid blue; margin:1em auto; }`

This will leave a space between the top and bottom of the element. You could wrap another element either way to make this effect larger or smaller, such as...

```
<div id="main-wrap">
  <p>Content here</p>
</div>
```

Then apply the effect to `main-wrap` and add a margin or padding to the `p`. Same thing only different if you apply it to `p` and not `div`, adjusting surrounding as needed.

Also: the border is more of a 'stroke' so "width" is "height" on vertical and so on.

### [Fiddle Yo.](http://jsfiddle.net/FXH9R/)